# Partition Map Check failed because no slices were found - External Drive

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, external-disk

I have a WD My Passport external drive which is giving me the runaround.

Yesterday I unplugged it from a Windows PC I was using without 'safely removing' because there was no icon in the system tray to allow me to do so. Instead I shut down the PC, waited for the drive to spin down and unplugged it.

That night I got home and plugged it into my MacBook, and immediately something seemed odd. The drive access light was flashing continuously for over an hour, and it the read write head was moving rapidly across the surface, despite not me not actively doing anything with the drive.

The drive mounted fine, and I was able to back up my files.

Having done this I started to investigate.

I ran Disk Utility and executed a verify disk. At the partition level 'Yellow', it ran fine and gave me "The volume 'Yellow' appears to be OK"

[image]

but when I tried this at the upper drive level "WD My Passport 25E1 Media" it came back with "Error: Partition Map Check failed because no slices were found"

[image]

I was also unable to eject the disk because "the disk could not be unmounted"

I have since plugged it back into the Windows PC I was using, a dialogue box popped up stating "there appears to be a problem with this drive" I let it go through the repair process and it repaired successfully.

I plugged it back into the MacBook, again it seems to mount correctly and my files are accessible. However when I open it in Disk Utilit and verify "WD My Passport 25E1 Media" it still returns "Error: Partition Map Check failed because no slices were found", and I'm still unable to eject the disk.

So my questions are:

Why does this error appear at the top 'drive' level, and not at the individual partition level?

What can I do to fix this?

Apologies in advance if I have misunderstood how the verify disk function works

**UPDATE 01-DEC-2019:**

As a control experiment, I have formatted an identical blank WD My Passport (also as ExFAT.) When I click the top level of the disk on this drive in Disk Utility, "Verify Disk" is greyed out completely, and then is clickable on the partition level... Is this correct behavior? Is this what the other drive should be doing? Or is it just because this is an empty drive?

Comment: The "... prevent booting" message is irrelevant - it just misses an EFI partition.